# Not able to connect ODBC Server and Driver

Tags: marklogic

I'm trying to connect an ODBC server and driver. I followed the instructions to set up an ODBC Server here: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/setup#id_65419 and to set up the ODBC Driver here: https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/sql/odbc-driver. I also tried watching https://mlu.marklogic.com/ondemand/3a33410a, but I haven't be able to figure out why I keep on getting this error message:

[image]

Comment: Try putting the IP address of your odbc server in the server box rather than the word sql

Comment: @twoleggedhorse That's awesome! Thank you! When I typed in 10.0.2.2, it worked. I've been struggling with this for a long time so I truly appreciate it!

Comment: @twoleggedhorse please add this as an answer, so that it's clear this one's been solved

Comment: @DaveCassel Done

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to either put the IP address of your odbc server into the `server` box or a fully qualified domain name if connected to a corporate network.